# Labyrinthus Londoninensis, or The Equestrian Perplexed

Tags: visual, mazes, puzzle-history

*This is far from an original puzzle, but I thought it fit our current fortnightly challenge so well that it ought to be included here.*

*I saw it on the* [Futility Closet](http://www.futilitycloset.com/2016/07/16/road-work-4/) *website, but it was originally created in 1830 by London printer Charles Ingrey.*

---

[image: Labyrinthus Londoninensis, or The Equestrian Perplexed]

-- *click the image for a more-detailed copy, or check out the [zoomable version at the British Library](http://www.bl.uk/onlinegallery/onlineex/crace/l/zoomify88508.html)* --

The puzzle states:

> *Mending our Ways, our ways doth oft-times mar,
>
>   So thinks the Traveller by Horse or Car,
>
>   But he who scans with calm and patient skill
>
>   This "Labyrinthine Chart of London", will
>
>   One Track discover, open and unbarred,
>
>   That leads at length to famed St. Paul's Church Yard.*

---

> #### *A PUZZLE*
>
> *Suggested by the Stoppages occasioned by repairing the Streets.  The object is to find a way from the Strand to St. Paul's, without crossing any of the Bars in the Streets supposed to be under repair.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found more than one route due to a couple of loops:

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

The red path in this image appears to me to work. The blobby grey bits are my scribblings to help clarify some impassable or pointless routes.

> [image: London]

Comment: A crash requiring reboot upon imgur upload meant your solution got here first, but basically the same. EDIT - judging by my comment post time to hypern you probably beat me by 10 seconds or so.

Comment: I got the same path as this, couple minutes slower.